# Google Protocol Buffer to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, meteor, protocol-buffers

Is there a simple way to convert Google Protocol Buffers to JSON in JavaScript (Meteor 1.4 or node.js)? 
I already have a .proto-File with the definition.

My usecase is:

- the server part searches for BLE-Devices (Bluetooth low energy)
- the manufacturer data is encoded as Protocol Buffer
- converting the Protocol Buffer to JSON in a simple way

I am using "[noble](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble)" as BLE-Library and i already tried to use ["protobuf.js"](https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js/), but i don't know how to convert the data into JSON (i am pretty new to JavaScript and the example code provided by protobuf.js looks complicated for me).